# How to excute a looping

Tags: css, while-loop

hi i'm currently working a project i want to display image on a table instead of declaring one-by-one how can i excute a while loop method in  CSS thanks :)

or how i excute a loop by accessing my database.

my codes:

```
</style>
<form>
  <table class="tbl-equipments">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan='4' class='td-search'>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search Equipment.." required/>
          <input type="button" value="Reserve" />
          <input type="button" value="Cancel" />

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 250px height: 250px">
            <img src="laptop_icon.jpg" alt="Laptop" style="width: 150px" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: css doesn't have loops...

Comment: CSS isn't what you are looking for here.  I assume you want to change laptop_icon.jpg for each list item.  You will need some sort of server side programming to do this.  Look at PHP, Ruby, etc

Comment: @BarbaraLaird Or a client side language like JS. I don't think this problem requires server side programming.

Comment: thanks @Barbaralaird is there any way to loop ?

Answer (score 0):

use css property

```
 background-repeat: repeat;
```

to repeat only horizontally , use `background-repeat: repeat-x`
to repeat only vertically, use `background-repeat: repeat-y`

source : [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp)